# Flutter_blue and Adafruit Bluefruit BLE characteristic error: could not locate CCCD descriptor for characteristic

Tags: android, flutter, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit

I am currently running into an issue with my ble project for flutter. I am using the flutter blue package by Paul DeMarco and the additional page for the app is based on "ThatProject" dust sensor from youtube.  I have an Adafruit Feather 32u4 board, and I am attempting to notify the client (my flutter app) that It has a series of numbers to send, but I am not getting any output. I am able to connect to the device, and seem to properly send the service UUID and characteristic UUID, but im not sure if it is coming with proper properties.
I am using the adafruit BLE code to program the board, and I can get the values if I use adafruit's app. I am just trying to get the values on my own flutter app.

I am running into an error as follows:

```
E/flutter (32139): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(set_notification_error, could not locate CCCD descriptor for characteristic: 6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e, null, null)
```

Here is my code. I believe the missing CCCD is coming from this part:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:oscilloscope/oscilloscope.dart';

class SensorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SensorPage({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;

  @override
  _SensorPageState createState() => _SensorPageState();
}

class _SensorPageState extends State<SensorPage> {
  final String SERVICE_UUID = "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
  final String CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
  bool isReady;
  Stream<List<int>> stream;
  List<double> traceDust = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isReady = false;
    connectToDevice();
  }

  connectToDevice() async {
    // if (widget.device == null) {
    //   // _Pop();
    //   return;
    // }

    //timeout timer, watchdog timer if you will
    new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 15), () {
      if (!isReady) {
        disconnectFromDevice();
        //   _Pop();
      }
    });

    await widget.device.connect();
    discoverServices();
  }

  disconnectFromDevice() {
    if (widget.device == null) {
      //_Pop();
      return;
    }

    widget.device.disconnect();
  }

  discoverServices() async {
    // if (widget.device == null) {
    //   //  _Pop();
    //   return;
    // }

    BluetoothCharacteristic ss;
    List<BluetoothService> services = await widget.device.discoverServices();
    services.forEach((service) {
      debugPrint("This Service UUID is!${service.uuid.toString()}");
      if (service.uuid.toString() == SERVICE_UUID) {
        service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
          debugPrint("This char UUID is!${characteristic.uuid.toString()}");
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == CHARACTERISTIC_UUID) {
            debugPrint("Here is !isNotifying: ${!characteristic.isNotifying}");
            debugPrint("Here is characteristic.value: ${characteristic.value}");
            ss = characteristic;
            stream = ss.value;
            setState(() {
              isReady = true;
            });
          } //this one
        });
      } //this one
    });
    await ss.setNotifyValue(true);
    stream = ss.value;
    if (!isReady) {
      // _Pop();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) =>
            new AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Are you sure?'),
              content: Text('Do you want to disconnect device and go back?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                    child: new Text('No')),
                new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      disconnectFromDevice();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                    },
                    child: new Text('Yes')),
              ],
            ) ??
            false);
  }

  // _Pop() {
  //   Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
  // }

  String _dataParser(List<int> dataFromDevice) {
    debugPrint("current value is-> ${utf8.decode(dataFromDevice)}");
    return utf8.decode(dataFromDevice);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Oscilloscope oscilloscope = Oscilloscope(
      showYAxis: true,
      padding: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      traceColor: Colors.white,
      yAxisMax: 3000.0,
      yAxisMin: 0.0,
      dataSet: traceDust,
    );

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Optical Dust Sensor'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: !isReady
                ? Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Waiting...",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    child: StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                      stream: stream,
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError)
                          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');

                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.active) {
                          debugPrint("snapshot.error: ${snapshot.error}.");
                          debugPrint("snapshot.data: ${snapshot.error}.");
                          debugPrint(
                              "snapshot.connectionState: ${snapshot.connectionState}.");
                          debugPrint("snapshot.hasdata?: ${snapshot.hasData}.");

                          var currentValue = _dataParser(snapshot.data);
                          traceDust.add(double.tryParse(currentValue) ?? 0);

                          return Center(
                              child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text('Current value from Sensor',
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                                      Text('$currentValue ug/m3',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 24))
                                    ]),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: oscilloscope,
                              )
                            ],
                          ));
                        } else {
                          return Text('Check the stream');
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// Copyright 2017, Paul DeMarco.
// All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:K9Harness/Pages/Sensor_page.dart';
import 'package:K9Harness/Bluetooth/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';

class MyBluetoothPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
          stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
          initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
              return FindDevicesScreen();
            }
            return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);
          }),
    );
  }
}

class BluetoothOffScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BluetoothOffScreen({Key key, this.state}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothState state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.bluetooth_disabled,
              size: 200.0,
              color: Colors.white54,
            ),
            Text(
              'Bluetooth Adapter is ${state.toString().substring(15)}.',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .primaryTextTheme
                  .subhead
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FindDevicesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Find Devices'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => FlutterBlue.instance
            .startScan(
                scanMode: ScanMode.balanced,
                withServices: [
                  Guid("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
                ], //FIXME check the other ways where ".startScan" is implemented
                timeout: Duration(seconds: 4))
            .catchError((error) {
          print("error starting scan $error");
        }),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothDevice>>(
                stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2))
                    .asyncMap((_) => FlutterBlue.instance.connectedDevices),
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map((d) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(d.name),
                            subtitle: Text(d.id.toString()),
                            trailing: StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
                              stream: d.state,
                              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected,
                              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.data ==
                                    BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
                                  return RaisedButton(
                                    child: Text('OPEN'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                DeviceScreen(device: d))),
                                  );
                                }
                                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                              },
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                          result: r,
                          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            r.device.connect();
                            return SensorPage(device: r.device);
                          })),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: FlutterBlue.instance.isScanning,
        initialData: false,
        builder: (c, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.stop),
              onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan(),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            );
          } else {
            return FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance
                        .startScan(
                            scanMode: ScanMode.balanced,
                            withServices: [
                              Guid("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
                            ], //FIXME check the other ways where ".startScan" is implemented
                            timeout: Duration(seconds: 4))
                        .catchError((error) {
                      print("error starting scan $error");
                    }));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeviceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DeviceScreen({Key key, this.device}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothDevice device;

  List<Widget> _buildServiceTiles(List<BluetoothService> services) {
    return services
        .map(
          (s) => ServiceTile(
            service: s,
            characteristicTiles: s.characteristics
                .map(
                  (c) => CharacteristicTile(
                    characteristic: c,
                    onReadPressed: () => c.read(),
                    onWritePressed: () => c.write([13, 24]),
                    onNotificationPressed: () =>
                        c.setNotifyValue(!c.isNotifying),
                    descriptorTiles: c.descriptors
                        .map(
                          (d) => DescriptorTile(
                            descriptor: d,
                            onReadPressed: () => d.read(),
                            onWritePressed: () => d.write([11, 12]),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(device.name),
        actions: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
            stream: device.state,
            initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
            builder: (c, snapshot) {
              VoidCallback onPressed;
              String text;
              switch (snapshot.data) {
                case BluetoothDeviceState.connected:
                  onPressed = () => device.disconnect();
                  text = 'DISCONNECT';
                  break;
                case BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected:
                  onPressed = () => device.connect();
                  text = 'CONNECT';
                  break;
                default:
                  onPressed = null;
                  text = snapshot.data.toString().substring(21).toUpperCase();
                  break;
              }
              return FlatButton(
                  onPressed: onPressed,
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .primaryTextTheme
                        .button
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                  ));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
              stream: device.state,
              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                leading: (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected)
                    ? Icon(Icons.bluetooth_connected)
                    : Icon(Icons.bluetooth_disabled),
                title: Text(
                    'Device is ${snapshot.data.toString().split('.')[1]}.'),
                subtitle: Text('${device.id}'),
                trailing: StreamBuilder<bool>(
                  stream: device.isDiscoveringServices,
                  initialData: false,
                  builder: (c, snapshot) => IndexedStack(
                    index: snapshot.data ? 1 : 0,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                        onPressed: () => device.discoverServices(),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: SizedBox(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          width: 18.0,
                          height: 18.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: null,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: device.mtu,
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                title: Text('MTU Size'),
                subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data} bytes'),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                  onPressed: () => device.requestMtu(223),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothService>>(
              stream: device.services,
              initialData: [],
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                return Column(
                  children: _buildServiceTiles(snapshot.data),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had my characteristic UUID to be `6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e` and it should have been `6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e` because for the feather, the notification/notify characteristic is mandatory to be `0x0003` instead of the `2`. It then passed the CCCD properly when I changed this value.