# flutter_blue set_notification_error, could not locate CCCD descriptor for characteristic

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I created a flutter demo app for BLE connection and communication.

I'm try listen the data from characteristic value. But doing the `await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);` will cause an error.

The code bellow is the whole operation from discovering services and read characteristic.

```
discoverServices() async {
List<BluetoothService> services = await discoveredDevice.discoverServices();
services.forEach((service) {
    service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) async {

        // Read characteristic
        var value = await characteristic.read();
        debugPrint("Read value: $value");

        // Read descriptor
        var descriptors = characteristic.descriptors;
        for(BluetoothDescriptor d in descriptors) {
          List<int> descriptorValue = await d.read();
          debugPrint("Descriptor value: $descriptorValue");
        }

        await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
        debugPrint('Is characteristic notifying: ${characteristic.isNotifying}');
        characteristic.value.listen((characteristicValue) {
          debugPrint('Characteristic value: $characteristicValue');
          setState(() {
            listStream = characteristic.value;
          });
        });
    });
});
```

And I encounter this error:

```
E/flutter (28172): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(set_notification_error, could not locate CCCD descriptor for characteristic: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, null, null)
```

All characteristic uuid from my BLE device have the error above.

Your answer/s will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66513806/6280156

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66513806/6280156 problem cause by typo mistake. In my case I have specific UUIDs and I'm sure it is correct. Does some characteristic don't have CCCD descriptor? And how to identify if it's CCCD descriptor. I'm really new to BLE connection and communication by the way.